# Jfrog Artifactory REST API Search for a latest version of an artifact

Tags: artifactory

I am trying to retrieve the latest version of an artifact with the following query

http://artifactory_domain/artifactory/api/search/latestVersion?g=groupId&a=artifactId&v=0.101.1&repos=repository_on_artifactory

Where :

1. artifactory_domain - domain name of your artifactory.
2. groupId - you can find it Artifact Repository Browser, please, look into a screen shot.
3. artifactId -you can find it Artifact Repository Browser, please, look into a screenshot.
4. Repo name where artifact persists.

[image]

which is assembled in accordance with the following documentation https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-ArtifactLatestVersionSearchBasedonLayout

However, it returns lastest in accordance with the alphabetical order. 
For example:

- 0.101.1
- 0.101.11
- 0.101.2

The query returns 0.101.2 despite the fact that there is version 0.101.11 already.

Is there any flag/option to retrieve the latest version based on the created date?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found answer by myself in documentation:

To change the retrieve latest behavior to retrieve the latest version based on the created date you can add the following flag to

- $ARTIFACTORY_HOME/etc/artifactory.system.properties

and add the following flag

- artifactory.request.searchLatestReleaseByDateCreated=true

and restart Artifactory service